# Analysis question of two continuous functions in the rationals being equivalent in the reals

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-writing

Suppose $f,g$ are continuous on $\Bbb{R}$ and $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{Q}$. Prove that $f(x) = g(x)$ $\forall$x $\in$ $\Bbb{R}$;

I realize this is a repeat of a question but they use topological references which i do not understand. Also I read the Rudin exercise but I still am confused, I was hoping someone could help me understand this from a analysis perspective that is cut and dry. Thank you.

Comment: Two related questions are https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177885/two-continuous-functions-that-are-the-same-in-the-rationals and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179810/prob-4-chap-4-in-baby-rudin-a-continuous-image-of-a-dense-subset-is-dense-in/2179934#2179934

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary $x \in \Bbb{R}$. You can find a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $x_n \in \Bbb{Q}$ for each $n$ and such that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=x
$$
(why?)

By hypothesis, $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$ for every $n$. Then,
$$
f(x)=f\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n) =g\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n\right)=g(x)
$$
Where the second and fourth equalities follow because $f$ and $g$ are continuous (why?).

Since $x$ is arbitrary in $\Bbb{R}$, this shows indeed that $f(x)=g(x)$, for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$